# What does foo mean?

Tags: java

I've seen a lot of people using "foo" as method names or class names in java on Stackoverflow and other things. What's foo? Is it just a generic name for any method, class, etc. or does it actually mean anything? And why foo? Is it only for java or do people use it for other languages too?

Comment: I doubt you're going to do better than the answer on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar).

Comment: you can look for `Foobar` in wikipedia, you have a whole page on the History and etymology :)

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69788/what-is-the-history-of-the-use-of-foo-and-bar-in-source-code-examples

Comment: http://qr.ae/TUIP8U

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's traditionally used for just a random name. Some other common ones are:

1. Foo
2. Bar
3. Quux
4. Baz

The supposed origin of foo and bar is that "FUBAR" was WWII slang for F***ed Up Beyond All Recognition. FUBAR  =>  FOOBAR  =>  Foo and Bar.

There isn't really a compelling reason to choose it besides the fact that no language reserves the word `foo` and that it's easy enough to type/read.

Answer (score 5):

It's a generic name for a thing, using in computer science in general. Etymologically, "foo" is the first syllable of "FUBAR", which is an acronym for "****ed Up Beyond All Recognition/Recovery".

Answer (score 2):

`foo` is a term used to represent something without you getting too attached to the meaning.  I could say `object a` in its place or literally anything else.

see examples 1 or 4 here: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=foo

Answer (score 0):

it is just an `identifier` which you can assign to `methods` or `classes` .